# How can I run multiple Neo4j databases on a single server?

Tags: neo4j

How can I run multiple Neo4j databases simultaneously on a single server? I would like to have separate data directories and ports if this is possible.

Has anyone done this successfully and if so explain how to do this

I have tried something like:

bin\neo4j start

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set up Neo4j with multiple instances on a single server, you essentially configure a cluster, with each node having its own set of configuration properties. You then run the cluster in single-instance (non-HA) mode (otherwise you'll just end up with a replication cluster, which doesn't meet your requirement).

Full instructions are in the [Neo4j docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha-setup-tutorial.html#ha-local-cluster) online and in your local `doc\manual` folder.

Note: The folks at Neo Technology call this out for dev/test purposes. I can't offer guidance on running this in production, other than the fact you'd have multiple instances competing for the same resources (cpu, disk, memory, network).

Comment: How were you able to set this up? I've looked in the docs but I don't find anything similar to what you described. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the docs have been changed. No matter: the key is to just install multiple copies to different locations, each with its own settings (to specify different graph data directory and different port).

Comment: How do I install multiple copies to different locations :0) ? Installation with apt-get surely doesn't allow me to install either to multiple locations, nor multiple copies. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to setup Rexster to serve up multiple neo4j database directories.  This is great if you're using the Gremlin query language.  Other access forms may not be available (beyond my knowledge).  Check out this question/answer: [possible to connect to multiple neo4j databases via bulbs/Rexster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315615/possible-to-connect-to-multiple-neo4j-databases-via-bulbs-rexster)